# Catch selected value from dynamic comboboxes inside itemscontrol in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, combobox, itemscontrol, selectedvalue

i got this problem when trying to get the selected value from a group of dynamic comboboxes i made inside a items control, to explain better here is my xaml code.

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControlP"
                      Width="120"
                      Margin="5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=personWindow, Path=DataContext.City}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Height="20"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=personWindow, Path=DataContext.Person}"
                              SelectedIndex="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

City and persons are ObservableCollection type, so for each city it shows a combobox and each combo box have a list of persons, then i need to catch the selected value in each combo box. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can get the selecteditem of the combobox like this,

```
    if (combobox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var x = (Person)combobox.SelectedItem;
        }
```

then you can access the entity of the object as x.name like that. Hope this helps to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping but i couldnt do it this way, i ended doing the catch by binding the selecteditem combobox property to one viewmodel property and i did the binding by code so i could index each combobox and it worked pretty good.